# OpenPop message.Save

Tags: outlook, openpop

I am trying to save the email msg as a file on the local drive.

```
 FileInfo msgfile = new FileInfo(Path.Combine(@"C:\\Users\\Public\\Documents\\msg-" + filenumber + ".msg"));
 getMessage.Save(msgfile);
```

But when I attempt to open the file Outlook gives me the following error

[image]

If i open the same file in Notepad i don't get any error.

Suggestions???

Regards

MRRCOMP

Comment: Which line of your code throws that error?

Answer (score 0):

I solved by saving with extension .eml and not msg

Hope this helps others

Regards

Comment: well, that wouldn't be an EML file.